# cannot find mvn/mvnDebug in mac

Tags: maven

i installed apache-maven-3.0.4 on mac 10.6.8, the bin folder structure is like this:

```
/usr/share/java/maven-3.0.4/bin/
  -- m2.conf
  -- mvn
  -- mvn.bat
  -- mvnDebug
  -- mvnDebug.bat
  -- mvnyjp
```

if i run 'mvn -v' as non-root user, i get:

```
-bash: maven: command not found
```

if i run as a root user, i got:

```
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_29, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.6.8", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

the same thing to 'mvnDebug', how can i fix this so that non-root user can access these commands? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set PATH to include /usr/share/java/maven-3.0.4/bin/. And make sure that the modes the entire tree are something like 755.

Comment: i did, i added it to .profile and when i ran 'export' command, i can see the path to mavn-3.0.4/bin was added to the path.

Comment: got it, forgot to change the permission on the maven-3.0.4 folder, i did the following then it works: chmod 755 maven-3.0.4